Cohomology of $G$-invariant forms is isomorphic to standard cohomology
At this link I found out about this rather interesting result. I'd like to understand the proof that is given under, but I'm quite unconfortable with some parts. First of all, while I know what a Haar measure on a Lie group is, I don't understand what the notation $\int_G g^* \beta$ is supposed to mean: since $\beta$ is a form on the manifold $M$ and we are considering it's pullback under the map $T_g \colon M \rightarrow M$ (given by the action of $G$), how can we integrate $g^*\beta = T_g^*\beta$ over $G$? The second thing I can't understand is why it should be $[\sigma] = T_{g*}([\sigma]) = [T_g \circ \sigma]$ for each simplex $\sigma \colon \Delta^k \rightarrow M$. Could somebody clarify this couple of things for me? Thanks in advance.

First pretend that G is a finite group, how would you make some differential form G invariant? What this is doing is summing the translates of a differential form and the output is another differential form on M.

What explicitly do you mean by $[\sigma]$ here? Are you wanting to argue that the integral a closed $k$-form $\beta$ over $\sigma$ is equal to the integral of $\tilde\beta$ over $\sigma$? I also object to the notation $T_g$ for the action of $G$ on $M$.

I would write $\tilde\beta=\int_G g^*\beta\,dg$ to be a bit more explicit. Perhaps this is one situation where it helps to evaluate on tangent vectors.
Writing $g\colon M\to M$, we have $g_*\colon T_pM\to T_{g(p)}M$ for any $p$. If $\beta$ is a $k$-form and $v_1,\dots,v_k\in T_pM$, then
$$\tilde\beta(p)(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \int_G \beta(g(p))(g_*v_1,\dots,g_*v_k)\,dg.$$
